# what should i do when it shows invalid literal for int() with base 10. I have scrutinized the whole syntax and there was no wrong information

Tags: python

```
Python 3.9.2 (tags/v3.9.2:1a79785, Feb 19 2021, 13:44:55) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> weight_lbs=input("weight(lbs)- ")
weight(lbs)- 46
>>> weight_kgs=int('weight_lbs')* 29
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'weight_lbs'
```

Answer (score 0):

`weight_kgs=int('weight_lbs')* 29` is trying to convert the literal *string* `"weight_lbs"` to an int. Just remove the quotes:

```
weight_kgs=int(weight_lbs)* 29
```

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in this line
`>>> weight_kgs=int('weight_lbs')* 29`

If you use double quotes or single quotes, python considers the value to be a string and not the variable you used before. We can fix this by doing

`>>> weight_kgs=int(weight_lbs)* 29`

This time we have removed the single quotes so it is a variable and not a string. So your code will work. If you are unable to understand why this is happening, let me know in comments and I will try to help